# Eclipse's Console & Logcat not print message after switch emulator from Android 2.2 to Google API (same API8)

Tags: android, android-emulator

After I switch from Eclipse Emulator from Andorid 2.2 to Google API (same level API8, I need Google map func). 
Console and Logcat doesn't print out message after the switch. I tried restart Eclipse and my pc still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

have you try to go in DDMS perspective and click on the device ( here Emulator ) and return to java perspective? Or click in logcat on the spinner who switch between debug,verbose etc?

Yes it's a little buggy xD